# Bibliometrix Package Installation Error

Tags: r, bibtex

Very simple place but somehow my code is going wrong and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
install.packages("bibliometrix", dependencies=TRUE) ### installs bibliometrix package and dependencies
library(bibliometrix)   ### load bibliometrix package
```

I'm really just trying to install the bibliometrix package but I'm getting this error:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’:
 object ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘bibliometrix’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

There's nothing else in my script so I'm really not sure what's going wrong here. Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of fixing this error is to update any R packages, which are used within the "bibliometrix" package (i.e. the dependencies). This should fix this problem (at least that is how I was able to fix the problem for my R installation - I use R Studio).

Per the [documentation](http://www.bibliometrix.org/), the dependencies can be updated/re-installed via the following:

> install.packages("dplyr", "factoextra", "FactoMineR", "ggplot2",
>   "igraph", "Matrix", "rscopus", "SnowballC", "stringr")

Once you (re)-install these packages, make sure you load them via seperate library commands or through *p_load* command from the [pacman package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/pacman.pdf).

Then, install the bibliometrix package and load it. This should solve your problem.